# How to count how many times an item has been repriced and markeddown in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a table called history and it contains all the historic data of the item and its different prices.

Here is an example of the table:

[image]

> Apologies for the photo, it's not letting me create tables at the
> minute

How would I count how many times the product has been repriced?

Also being marked down doesn't mean it's always repriced as markdown could be '0' but the sale price as been altered through the weeks.

Comment: I would assume that in order to give you an accurate script, more data is required. Please provide us with more data, what you have tried and your expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each record in the table means that the item has been repriced (and because I not know what your expected results are), you can get the results with the following script:

```
declare @tbl table
(
    id                  int primary key identity
,   dDate               date
,   sku                 varchar(50)
,   markdown            float
,   cost_price          float
,   original_price      float
,   current_sale_price  float
)

insert into @tbl
(
    dDate
,   sku
,   markdown
,   cost_price
,   original_price
,   current_sale_price
)
values
    ('2020-01-07','A124-WZ876',0,4.5,5,5)
,   ('2020-01-07','A124-WZ876',1,4.5,15,3.75)
,   ('2020-01-07','A124-WZ876',1,4.5,4,4)
,   ('2020-01-14','A124-WZ876',1,4.5,15,4)
,   ('2020-01-21','A124-WZ876',1,4.5,15,7.5)
,   ('2020-01-07','A124-WZ875',1,4.5,4,4)
,   ('2020-01-14','A124-WZ875',1,4.5,15,4)
,   ('2020-01-07','A124-WZ874',1,4.5,15,3.75)
,   ('2020-01-07','A124-WZ875',1,4.5,4,4)
,   ('2020-01-14','A124-WZ874',1,4.5,15,4)

select
    dDate   date
,   sku
,   markdown
,   cost_price
,   original_price
,   current_sale_price
,   row_number() over (partition by sku order by id)    RevaluedTimes
from    @tbl
order by sku
```

Notice that I've added more `sku's` to the source data to give you a clear indication how the count works.

This provides you with the following results:

[image: Results]

Also see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fcf8e0bf7a50e536715036f929eb74be)